# Rigidbody behaves differently when I select another gameobject in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

This the strangest thing i ever saw, i swear! So i have a script to the player that when you click on screen the cube jumps in the direction of the arrow(the arrow rotates 360 degres).I changed some settings to the rigidbody2d to make the jump better.Now here comes the strange part,when i run the game and the player is selected in the scene or hierrachy the jump works fine,if i select something else for exemple the camera something chenges the jump,from a very good one to a very bad one,i tryed to build the project and test and is the same,the cube dosen't have the same "Jump".I think it's becouse i changed something in the rigidbody,idk.PLS HELP!!!center
P.S if u ask for the script here it is :

```
public void Update()
{
    Lava.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, Lava.transform.position.y);//other,not important
    cam.transform.position = transform.position + offset;//camera follow player
    Arrow.transform.RotateAround(gameObject.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, 180), ArrowSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //to make the arrow rotate 360
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rb.AddForce(Arrow.transform.right * -ImpulseForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse); //this makes the cube jump       
    }
    //other
    score = (int) transform.position.y;
    ScoreUI.text = score.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You put your physics code into Update method which depends on deltaTime which is not a fixed number. You must put your physics code into FixedUpdate method and use fixedDeltaTime.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) method takes a normalized vector as its second parameter, such as Vector3.forward in your case.

Secondly, applying any force to a rigidbody should be done in FixedUpdate, not Update (see [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) and [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html))

In your case it's an impulse, and it's only called when you click, so no need to multiply by delta time.

```
rb.AddForce(Arrow.transform.right * -ImpulseForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

It may not solve all of your issues, but without further information it's tough to know. At least you wont have weird physics behaviors anymore.

Comment: So here is how i fixed it, i just multiplied ImpulseForce with Time.fixedDeltaTime,i also moved it in fixed update function but there dosen't work at all and i replaced it in update and works perfectly.Thanks for help everyone <3 :)